# Why canvas.getContext("2d")? Why not only canvas.getContext()?

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas

If a canvas is always 2d then why in the world are we specifying the 2d parameter in `getContext()` function. Why isn't it only `getContext()`, why is it with a fixed parameter? :O

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 parameters which `getContext()` can take. One is the standard 2d context which renders 2d elements. The other uses webGL technology which is still in its infancy. Hence mostly you will find the 2d context of canvas everywhere (as of now).


Just as 3ds max or photoshop is a **2d window on your computer screen** but you can render 3d stuff through them. Similarly, canvas is a **2d element in your browser** through which you can change the context and render appropriate output.

Answer (score 1):

It's not "always 2D". You can use `WebGL` to make 3D graphics, or other parameters accepted by  `getContext`

Microsoft has a detailed explanation on the parameters [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff975238%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).